# Using labels in Alertmanager webhook

Tags: prometheus

My alert configure as follows.

```
ALERT PoDHighCPUUsage
  IF sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace!=""}[2m])) BY (kubernetes_pod_name, kubernetes_io_hostname, container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace) >= 0.2
  FOR 2m
  LABELS {severity="criticalup"}
  ANNOTATIONS {summary="CPU usage of POD {{ $labels.kubernetes_pod_name }} {{ $labels.container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace }} utilization is  >= 0.4 cores (current value: {{ $value }}%)"}
```

My webhooks as follows ..

```
- name: 'email-n-webhookup'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'mail-id'
    send_resolved: true

  webhook_configs:
  - url: http://<webhook_ip>:9000/hooks/ose-webhook?in1={{.Labels.container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace}}&in2={{.Labels.kubernetes_pod_name}}&in3=plus

- name: 'email-n-webhookdn'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'mail-id'
    send_resolved: true

  webhook_configs:
  - url: http://<webhook_ip>:9000/hooks/ose-webhook?in1=tomi&in2=chat&in3=minus
```

I am not able to pass the value/data "labels.kubernetes_pod_name" & "labels.container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace" in webhook_configs.

Statically it worked as per "email-n-webhookdn"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all fields are templatable, and the webhook URL is one of those. It's expected that the code receiving the webhook will look inside the json it receives in the POST to get all the alerts and their labels.

Comment: Thanks Brain .. is there any alternate solution ?

Comment: Do this inside the webhook handler, not via URL parameters.